# Jackon json string to Java object using generics

Tags: java, json, string, generics, jackson

I've seen numerous posts related to my below query but unable to find exactly how to handle this issue:
I've a class as below:

```
  public class MyClass<T> implements IMyInterface<String, T> {

       @Override
       public T myMethod(String jsonString) {
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           //T result = mapper.readValue(jsonString, T.class) //for sure T.class does not make sense, but what is the alternative ?
       }
}
```

I want to use this class as a util class for any client who can pass on their json string to the `myMethod` and get the desired Java object that maps to the class they mention while instantiating `MyClass`.
So as an example,a client code that does

```
MyClass<MyType1> o1 = new MyClass<MyType1>();
MyType1 myType1 = o1.myMethod(aJsonString);
```

get an instance of `MyType1`

and another code that does

```
MyClass<MyType2> o2 = new MyClass<MyType2>();
MyType2 myType2 = o2.myMethod(anotherJsonString);
```

get an instance of `MyType2`

I'm seeing many posts related to TypeReference and JavaType usage but not able to get hold of exactly how to fit them for my above use case.

My main objective is that `MyClass` should actually act as a util class without knowing at compile time what is the Java object it will convert the input json string to. It should decide that at runtime only.

Any help will be highly appreciated !

Many thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution works for you. Have a private instance of type Class and initialize it in constructor.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class MyClass<T> implements IMyInterface<String, T> {

   private Class<T> clazz;

   public MyClass(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
   }

   @Override
   public T myMethod(String jsonString) throws Exception {
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       T result = mapper.readValue(jsonString, clazz); 
       return result;
   }
```

}

You client code will be :

```
MyClass<MyType1> o1 = new MyClass<MyType1>(MyType1.class);
MyType1 myType1 = o1.myMethod(aJsonString);
```

**ADDED answer for second question :**

In spring context file, define your bean as below.

```
<bean id="simpleMyType1Class" class="com.yourpackage.MyClass">
<constructor-arg>
    <!-- this can be any full path to a class -->
   <value>com.yourpackage.MyType1</value> 
</constructor-arg>
```

In Java code, get its bean reference as below.

```
MyClass<MyType> o1 = (MyClass)context.getBean("simpleMyType1Class");
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I need to instantiate MyClass through Spring via property/constructor injection (through XML configuration) ? How do I inject "clazz" ?

Comment: Look at the answer to your second.

Comment: The second question is irrelevant to the original post as this is related to spring framework. I am advising you to post a new question  in such cases because there is a possibility of me not knowing answer to the latter one and your question might not reach to respective spring tech guys.