# in java how to get a generic interface from spring

Tags: java, spring

I have an interface like

```
public interface IABC<T>{...}
```

and I have another method like

```
public IABC<T> Get<T>(Class<T> t){...}
```

In this method, I want to use a service locator with Spring.

```
applicationContext.getBean(?);
```

it needs `IABC<T>.class`, but it is wrong.
How can I get the `IABC<T>.class`?
It is so diffrent from C#

Comment: I think in the applicationContext.getBean(?), u need the instance object which implements the IABC<T> interface. So that Spring can find that instance in the context and return the reference.

Comment: [Check if this helps] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33206985/5038825)